# What is a regex to replace "### " with "###. "

Tags: regex, openoffice-writer

where ### is a three or four digit number followed by a space and I want to replace it with the same number followed by a space and a period.

I am using the regex search & replace in Open Office and I tried

```
"[0-9][0-9][0-9] "
```

which found the numbers I was looking for

replace with

```
$&
```

or

```
"[0-9][0-9][0-9]. "
```

neither worked

Comment: Something along the lines of `s/([0-9]{3,4}) /\1\. /g` would do it, but, what @FatalError said...

Answer (score 1):

In most regex implementations, "(\D\d{3,4}) " selects a 3 or 4 digit number with a nondigit prefix (otherwise it would find the 2345 in 12345). This way in ">1234 <" it will find ">1234 ", and put it in $1 or \1. So:

```
  s/(\D\d{3,4}) /\1. /g
```

Otherwise instead of \D you can use a word boundary, \< or \b or < depending on the dialect.

Edit: if \d is not supported, as in (apparently) my command line sed, even if I could have sworn to the contrary, use [0-9] to replace \d:

```
 sed -e 's/\([^0-9][0-9]\{3,4\}\) /\1. /g'
```

Test:

```
 $ echo "This is 12345 and 1234 and 123 and 12 and 1. 123. 1234." \
   | sed -e 's/\([^0-9][0-9]\{3,4\}\) /\1. /g'
```

Result:

```
 This is 12345 and 1234. and 123. and 12 and 1. 123. 1234.
```

Comment: `\D*` won't work anyway.  If there happen to be any non-digits before the number, `\D*` will match them, but it doesn't *prevent* anything from matching there--even digits.

Comment: True. I had removed the asterisk but did not update the first half of the answer. +Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work in OpenOffice 3.3:

Search: `([^0-9][0-9]{3,4})` (with trailing space)

Replace: `$1.` (with trailing space)

Unfortunately, it won't match a 3- or 4-digit number at the start of the text.